# PrimeNG: p-tabview - How to set an active Index on a specific header?

Tags: tabs, primeng, angular10

I have a common edit component where I am using p-tabview with multiple tab panels. I have another report component from where I need to call the edit component ( which I am able to do but it shows the first tab) and need help with highlighting a particular tab instead of the first tab. How can I achieve this.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

on your init, make your currentIndex = {number} tabnumber you want to show on your load.

for example you want to show your 3rd tab

```
   this.currentIndex = 2;
```